# Messed up IP table rules and locked myself out while setting firewall on SSH

Tags: ssh, security, iptables, firewall, vps

I was trying to set firewall rules to my website but I messed up with IP table rules and locked out myself. Now, I can't access to the VPS via SSH. When I try it I get that message:

`ssh: connect to host [IP address] port [Port]: Connection timed out`

Firstly, I have done those steps for setting the firewall rules. And after `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP` I think I've blocked myself as I couldn't add any command after all.

[image: steps for setting firewall rules]

So, what can I do for fixing this problem and add a strong firewall?

*Note 1: I'm new in those stuff and trying to learn it tho, 
Note 2: I don't have access to instance’s management page but I can ask my friend who is hosting the website to do stuff. So priority fixation can be on SSH*

Thanks Beforehand!

Comment: If there's nothing set up to make the rules persistent, just reboot the box and your rules will be wiped.

Comment: As for making sure this doesn't happen again, I just schedule a reboot 10 minutes in the future and if my rules work I cancel it. Simple and quick. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to regain access via ssh. You have to contact your friend and ask him to reset the iptables' rules.

If I can give you a suggestion, I would configure a watchdog using `cron` or `at` while configuring iptables, so it won't happen again.
I think you can find useful [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/451104/how-do-you-test-iptables-rules-to-prevent-remote-lockout-and-check-matches) and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/300566/how-to-regain-ssh-access-after-beeing-locked-out-by-iptables/300569) on ServerFault.